# How to create a new case in Petriflow language?

Tags: application-server, petri-net

How do I create a new case in actions in Petriflow language? I have tried createCase().

[image: Code I tried in builder.netgrif.com]

Answer (score 2):

In Petriflow in Action API function `createCase` has several signatures,
but you always must at least provide Net/Process from which you want to create a case.
One usage is provide process identifier as a string and the another is provide a PetriNet object.

You can read more in official documentation https://petriflow.com/#/actions?id=createcase.